# Gambler’s ruin probability

Tags: probability, gambling

A gambler enters casino with $k$ dollars and he starts betting $1$ dollar each time, with probability $1/2$ he wins $1$ dollar, and with probability $1/2$ he loses his bet (1 dollar), and to win he needs to reach $n$ dollars before getting ruined.

So if he reaches $n>k$ amount, then he wins and leaves, or he loses all his money and leaves.

> Find a formula to calculate the probability of the gambler’s winning using $n$ and $k=1$, and $p= 1/2$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: In case the answers to the original question linked to above are not at the level that you were aiming for, you can find a lot of further questions and answers on this and similar problems on the site by searching for "gambler's ruin" or "simple random walk", e.g. together with terms like "absorbing boundaries".

Answer (score 0):

Hint: let $p_n$ denote  the probability that he wins starting with $n$ dollars.

then $P_n= pP_{n+1}+(1-p)P_{n-1}$, with $P_0=0, P_k=1$.

Let's suppose that the solution is of the form $P_n= \theta^n$(From techniques for solving ODE).

Substitute to get

$\theta^n=p\theta^{n+1}+(1-p)\theta^{n-1} \Rightarrow \theta=p\theta^2+(1-p)$

and solving it we get $\theta =1, \frac{1-p}{p}$
So we get $a_1+ a_2(\frac{q}{p})^n$ to be a solution.

But $0=P_0=a_1+a_2$ and $1=P_k=a_1+a_2(\frac{q}{p})^k$.

to get : $$a_2=\frac{1}{(\frac{q}{p})^k-1}$$.

SO then the solution is , for general settings, $$\frac{-1}{(\frac{q}{p})^k-1}+\frac{1}{(\frac{q}{p})^k-1}(\frac{q}{p})^k$$.

Right?

Comment: You can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs. (That's particularly relevant for legibility if you use nested fractions and exponents.)